# Python plotnine increase distance between tick marks

Tags: python, ggplot2, bar-chart, python-ggplot, plotnine

I am trying to create a grouped bar chart using plotnine ggplot.

[bar graph](http://[1]:%20https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmjE6.png)

As you can see the x tick marks are too close to each other and the labels are cluttered. How can I increase the distance between these tick labels?

```
ggplot(test, aes(x = 'genre_pairs', y = 'average_rating', fill = 'group')) 
+geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) 
+scale_x_discrete (expand = np.array([0.2,0]))
```

is what I have so far

Comment: From the answers, it seems it is not possible. Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the plot wider by specifying the right figure size. You may find it helpful to rotate the text.

```
... + theme(figure_size=(11, 6), axis_text_x=element_text(rotation=45)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also rotate text directions by using theme(axis_text_x=element_text(angle=30, hjust=1, vjust=1)). For any occasion like this you can use it to discern x tick labels.